# PostgreSql command to see the table data

Tags: postgresql, command

I am new in PostgreSql. I import the database on my linux machine. I am able to see the list of tables using \d command (`GSM_test_db-# \d default_msg_details`) its displaying the table list but I want to see the table data.

Any Command that shows table Data also Please tell me.

I already used select query `GSM_test_db-# SELECT * FROM default_msg_details` but its not displaying anything and its not giving any error.

Please tell me if any command or why this select its not displaying anything.

Answer (score 23):

Because you need to terminate your statement with a `;`

Comment: On adding ";", it gives following error message: 
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM default_table;

Comment: I found the answer here. In addition to adding a semicolon, we need to turn off pagination : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180179/postgresql-disable-more-output

Answer (score 12):

Try `SELECT * FROM "default_msg_details";`

Beside adding ";" at the end of your query, you also need add the quotes("") to your tabel's name as well.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to disable pagination but retain the output:

```
\pset pager off
```

Then, use the below query:

```
SELECT * FROM "default_msg_details";
```