# PostgreSQL disable more output

Tags: postgresql, psql, pager

I am running a script on my PostgreSQL server:

```
psql db -f sql.sql
```

from `bash` or in a `cron` script.

It keeps trying to paginate the output with `more` or `less`.

How do I disable result pagination in `psql`?

All I want to do is change the data, I don't care about any output.

Answer (score 294):

To disable pagination but *retain* the output, use:

```
\pset pager off
```

To remember this setting, add it to your [~/.psqlrc](https://github.com/mcandre/dotfiles/blob/master/.psqlrc), e.g. like this: `echo \\pset pager off >> ~/.psqlrc`

See [the psql manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-psql.html).

On older versions of Pg it was just a toggle, so `\pset pager`

To completely suppress query output, use `\o /dev/null` in your `psql` script.

To suppress `psql`'s informational output, run it with `-q` or set `QUIET=1` in the environment.

---

To produce results and throw them away you can redirect `stdout` to `/dev/null` with:

```
psql db -f sql.sql >/dev/null
```

You can redirect both stdout and stderr with:

```
psql db -f sql.sql >&/dev/null
```

but I don't recommend that, as it'll throw away error information that might warn you something isn't going right. You're also producing results and throwing them away, which is inefficient; you're better off just not producing them in the first place by adjusting your queries.

Comment: That stops it from using a pager but it doesn't stop the output, no? I'm guessing you'd need `PAGER="/dev/null" psql db -P pager=always -f sql.sql` to make it always kill output.

Answer (score 142):

I was looking for this too, I found the way in a [similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/235184/turn-off-pager-for-psqls-interactive-output) on ServerFault:

```
psql -P pager=off <other params>
```

turns off the paging thing, without suppressing output.

Comment: This answer was more helpful than anything about -P in the man pages. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Here's another option. It does have the advantage that you don't have to remember psql option names, etc.

```
psql ... | cat
```

Answer (score 12):

bash, being a [shell](http://en.kioskea.net/contents/unix/unix-shell.php3), has 2 [streams](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html) you can redirect that output data: stdout and stderr, because this output needs to be redirected somewhere, linux has a specific 'discard everything' node reachable through [/dev/null](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/null). Everything you send there will just disappear into the void.

(shells also have an input stream but I'll ignore this here since you asked for suppressing output)

These streams are represented by numbers: 1 for stdout and 2 for stderr.

So if you want to redirect just stdout you'd do that with the `<` and `>` operators (basically where it points to is where the data flows to)

suppose we want to suppress stdout (redirect to /dev/null):

`psql db -f sql.sql > /dev/null`

As you can see this is stdout is default, no stream number has been used
if you wanted to use the stream number you'd write

`psql db -f sql.sql 1> /dev/null`

Now if you want to suppress stderror (stream number 2), you'd use

`psql db -f sql.sql 2> /dev/null`

You could also redirect one stream to another, for example stderror to stdout, which is useful if you want to save all output somewhere, regular and errors.

`psql db -f sql.sql 2>&1 > log.txt`

mind you there can not be spaces between `2>&1`

Finally and sometimes most interesting is the fact that you can suppress all output by using `&>`, for when you want it 'perfectly quiet'

`psql db -f sql.sql &> /dev/null`

Comment: While this info is sound in principle, it doesn't work at all in this specific case, because psql does not send the informative messages to stderr. They are intermingled with data on stdout.

Comment: Suddenly I realise that your point is that the final '&>' case can be used by the OP to stop the pager, by suppressing all output. I'll remove my downvote if you amend your answer in any way.

Answer (score 9):

```
psql -U user -P pager=off -d database -c 'SQL';
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)

Answer (score 6):

```
psql db -f sql.sql > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 3):

That is called ***PAGER***

Just input `\pset pager 0` into the command, **to turn off**

then

Enter `\pset pager 1` if you want to turn it **on** again. It used for long output

Answer (score 1):

This syntax worked for me in an SSH session:

```
psql db user --command "select * from table007" -A -P pager
```