# customize pager in psql

Tags: postgresql, command-line, psql, pager

When I use `psql`, the command line tool of PostgreSQL, in interactive mode, it lists data as paginated output.

However, because I use `psql` in a terminal application which can handle long outputs itself, I rather would like to get the whole output without the paginating with the annoying `--more--` line.

Is there any way to customise the paging behavior in `psql`? I tried to set `LESS` in the surrounding shell environment to `cat`, but this din't help.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

From the [fine `psql` manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html):

> `\pset option [ value ]`
>   [...]
>   `pager`
>   Controls use of a pager
>   program for query and psql help output. If the environment variable
>   `PAGER` is set, the output is piped to the specified program.
>   Otherwise a platform-dependent default (such as `more`) is used.
>
> When the `pager` option is off, the pager program is not used. When the pager option is on, the pager is used when appropriate

So you can say this from the `psql` prompt:

```
psql> \pset pager off
```

to turn the pager off. If you want this to always apply, you can add `\pset pager off` to your `~/.psqlrc` file.

You can also use `\?` from the `psql` prompt to get a quick summary of the special commands at your disposal.

Comment: Thanks for this. I should have found it myself in the help, but because of the pager I never got to the `\pset` command. ;-)

Comment: It is so nice to do this... export PAGER="vim -c 'set nomod nolist syntax=sql' -" and then use psql ...!

Comment: For anyone coming here years later: `\pset` is case-sensitive!!!

Comment: Just a word to tell that there is apparently no way to force the pager value to **on**. It's either off or "long output". Which is in some case (long field content, low record count) not working properly >_<

Comment: @RomualdBrunet Maybe `\x auto` would help.

Comment: Note: if you're using the postgres user, the change to ~/.psqlrc for it to be permanent will not work

Answer (score 3):

For completeness we might mention that for a one-off or to use as a setting in one of your scripts... (and as mentioned by "mu", see the psql --help (manual))

As a command in a script

> psql  --pset=pager-off  -c "`<sqlCommand>`"  `<databaseName>`

From your commandline

> psql  --pset=pager=off  `<databaseName>`

This would be in effect for the single command only so it is most useful in a script.

You can use this method in lieu of making temporary changes within the psql utility or permanent settings via the init file (~/.psqlrc).

Comment: I wonder if the answer given here is for a different version of `psql`.  This did not work for me.  The following worked for me: `psql -P pager=off <other params>`, via https://stackoverflow.com/a/15621397/320399

Comment: There is typo:  Use `--pset=pager=off` instead of `psql --pset=pager-off`