# Bash with docker exec don't go down when there's more content to show

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm running the docker exec command to run commands in a container, like this:

```
docker exec -it d52b251308b3 bash
```

The issue is that when it happens that the content is too long and the console show --More--, I can't scroll down to see the hidden content.

Comment: What command are you running when you're inside the container that's causing you to run out of screen space?

Comment: \d in postgress shell

Comment: You can try `\pset pager off` to disable the pager, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14474666/2297365 for more info.

Comment: Are there any other warnings or errors? I wonder if this is related to missing `PAGER` like https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-postgresql/issues/63

Comment: What I did was to install zsh in the container and use zsh instead, that way I can see all the content...