# IN sql psql i am not able to see my table and ending with this error

Tags: windows, postgresql, psql

```
postgres=# \d
'more' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data, your code and the desired output.

Comment: `more` is a **very** common pager application. It is used to present multiple screens of text in a way that lets you "page" through them. You can [turn it off](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14474666/2970947): `\pset pager off` (see link for how to set that as a default - or set a pager that you have installed).

Answer (score 0):

Your Windows system (it must be Windows) is crippled, because it lacks `more`.

You will have to start `psql` like this:

```sh
psql -P pager=off
```

This will work, but your `psql` experience will be even worse than normal on Windows.

Comment: It *could* be the world's strangest docker image. Couldn't it? Is `more` a cmd built-in? I know Windows has `more`. But I always install cygwin when I have to use Windows, so maybe that's why I never hit this message.