# Postgres sql insert query syntax error from phpPgAdmin

Tags: sql, postgresql, phppgadmin

Trying to execute a standard insert query, but it doesn't work.

```
INSERT INTO users (vk_id, eu_name, eu_society, eu_notes, eu_want_team)
VALUES ("123123133","Eu name","Eu society","Eu notes","true")
```

The error I get is the following:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INTO" LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS
 total FROM (INSERT INTO users (vk_id, eu_...
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: The error message is showing you the error: `SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM (INSERT ...`

Comment: I dont have any clues.... I dont have SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM so i dont know where it is taken

Comment: Are all those double-quotes okay in postgresql?  The documentation I'm looking at just shows single quotes.  And does it need a terminating semicolon?

Comment: BTW: the strings inside the values need to be in single quotes: `VALUES(123123133,'Eu name','Eu society','Eu notes',true)`

Comment: How are you running the query? Through a GUI or command line interface? Or produced in some other language/framework?

Comment: Tried with single quotes too, no effect.

Comment: Keep the single quotes, it would be the next error when you figure out how that  `SELECT COUNT(*)` found its way into the code.

Comment: i tried in Php postgres admin (ppa) and from code.

Comment: Trick #1: introduce a deliberate syntax error at the beginning: `BARF; INSERT INTO users (vk_id, eu_name, eu_society, eu_notes, eu_want_team) VALUES( ... );` The semicolon forces the parser to resync.

Comment: Well, this could be a bug in phpPgAdmin, I see a report opened in May: [Bugs item #3612602, was opened at 2013-05-03](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=30803741)

Comment: possible duplicate of [INSERT INTO PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18420742/insert-into-postgresql)

Answer (score 45):

I've installed phpPgAdmin to try to reproduce your error. I got it right away when tried to create a test table:

[image]

So looks like phpPgAdmin wraping your query into `select count(*) as total from (...)`. I've found that it happens only when **checkbox "Paginate results"** on query page is set to on (obviously phpPgAdmin trying to count how many rows it will get and then show it page by page). Uncheck it and your query will work fine:

[image]

**updated 1**

Similar question - [INSERT INTO PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18420742/insert-into-postgresql)

**updated 2**

As @akshay mentioned in comments, you also could get similar error running the queries through the command line, see explained situation and answer here - [PostgreSQL disable more output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180179/postgresql-disable-more-output)

Comment: @Roman Pekar I am getting a similar error, but i am not using pgadmin UI. I am running the commands through command line. How can i rectify the error?

Comment: I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180179/postgresql-disable-more-output

Comment: i've got blank SQL error: In statement:
without checkbox "Paginate results"

Answer (score 2):

The phpPgAdmin UI provides two links for running SQL - one in the main body of the page, and one in the menu bar at the top of the page.

The one in the main body of the page will throw the error you're seeing if you run a data definition statement like CREATE TABLE.

However, the one in the menu bar will run data definition queries with no problem.

In short:

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpImT.png)

Answer (score 0):

you could try this as well

`INSERT INTO "user" ("username", "password_hash", "first_name", "last_name")
VALUES( 'Foo',MD5('54321'),'Foo','Bar' );`