# PostgreSQL - Synax error in Update Query

Tags: postgresql, phppgadmin

Please check the query below.

```
update product set product_price = 5 where product_price = 0
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "set" at character 45
```

SQL error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "set" at character 45
```

In statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM (update product set product_price = 5 where product_price = 0) AS sub
```

I don't know why I am getting this error. Please help me.

Comment: Your statement does not make any sense. Why are you wrapping the `update` into a `select`. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: It's a `phppgadmin` problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368831/postgres-sql-insert-query-syntax-error

Comment: @DanielVérité is correct! Just unclick the checkbox "Paginate Results"...

Answer (score 1):

`update` statement does not return values which can be used in select.

If you want to know how many rows were affected you, [according to this](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Getting-number-of-affected-row-after-performing-update-td1920717.html) can use

`GET DIAGNOSTICS my_variable = ROWCOUNT;`

There are ways to do it programatically, but how to do it depends on the language used.

Comment: Thanks...I could not able to execute update query. I am getting an error. do you know why?

Comment: Because your query is invalid! You can not use update as subquery for a select. This is not possible in postgres.

Comment: Please understand, my question is update product set product_price = 5 where product_price = 0
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "set" at character 45. That's solve. I got the select query in phppgadmin response.

Comment: The problem is not the update, the problem is the select that is used around the update; remove the select, leave the update statement only and it will work properly.

Comment: OMG!!! I just pasted the above update query alone in phppgadmin. After that executed it. The Phppgadmin returned the "SQL error:" and "In statement:" lines in Error window. Is it clear?

Comment: I don't understand why are you getting angry. You are not being clear, I am trying to help you. Remember that. Your update syntax is fine. Maybe you're missing a schema name? or it's not product but product**s**?

Comment: @Dariusz that's right, phppgadmin does this. and this is valid

Comment: Really Sorry Dariusz!!..Thanks Keltar.

Comment: @user2003356 are you 100% sure table and column names are correct? Because i see nothing wrong with query

Comment: `GET` is `plpgsql` only.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto the question is explicitely about pgsql, as tag suggests.

Comment: `plpgsql` is a procedural language used to build Postgresql functions. It is not sql. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql.html

Comment: @keltar, I am sure. It is right.

Answer (score 1):

```
with s as (
    update product
    set product_price = 5
    where product_price = 0
    returning product_price
)
select count(*)
from s
```

Comment: Thanks Neto, but I am getting "SQL error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "as" at character 39".

Comment: @user What version of Postgresql? `select version();`

Comment: It works ok. Check this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/b55e1/2

Comment: Version: PostgreSQL 8.1.23 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)

Comment: @user `with` is a 8.4+ feature. Upgrade to 9.2 immediately.

Comment: For most people, including myself, upgrading is not an option

Answer (score 0):

The SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM ( yourquery ) wrapping seems to be caused by having the checkbox "paginate results" checked. If you uncheck that box, your update should work.