# Why am I getting a syntax error on my PostgreSQL SQL?

Tags: postgresql, phppgadmin

```
CREATE TABLE members (
    memberID SERIAL,
    username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    active VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    resetToken VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    resetComplete VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT 'No',
    CONSTRAINT members_pk PRIMARY KEY (memberID)
);
```

I am trying to use the provided statement in my PostgreSQL db, but when I attempt to execute it I am getting a syntax error:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CREATE"
> LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM (CREATE TABLE members (
> ```

As far as I know, my SQL is fine. I am not sure what is going wrong here.

Comment: It's not Postgres' fault.  It's a bug in the tool you're using to run the query, which I'm guessing is phpPgAdmin. If so, you can prevent it by [disabling pagination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368831/postgres-sql-insert-query-syntax-error).

Comment: Nick, you were correct in your assumption and your suggestion. Thanks! This is my first go-round with PostgreSQL and it's been a frustrating experience. Since you posted as a comment, however, I cannot accept your response as the answer.

Answer (score -3):

```
CREATE TABLE members (
    memberID SERIAL CONSTRAINT members_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    active VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    resetToken VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    resetComplete VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT 'No'
);
```

Does moving constraint syntax help?