# How to insert new row in Postgres table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, phppgadmin

i'm using for the first times Postgres and i'm experiencing problems adding a new row by SQL code.

Here is my table structure:

[image]

And here is the code that i'm executing:

```
INSERT INTO recensione (testo, voto, utente, merchant) VALUES
('this is a text', 2, 'username', 1234567);
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INTO" LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS     total FROM (INSERT INTO recensione (testo...
```

I'm sure it is easy to solve, but i'm getting crazy about it.
Thank you.

Comment: Based on the error you seem to have the `INSERT INTO` as a sub-query of something else.

Comment: Show all code involved please. You don't have `SELECT COUNT(*)...` in the code shown...

Comment: That's not the script you're executing.

Comment: Please do not downvote me, the query i posted above is that i'm executing!

Comment: Do not use PhpPgAdmin. In any reasonable SQL editor you wont get such error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it happens only when checkbox "Paginate results" on query page is set to on. Try unchecking that.

try looking at this example. 
[Postgres sql insert query syntax error from phpPgAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368831/postgres-sql-insert-query-syntax-error)

Comment: Works, thank you! Someone downvote my question because was not so expert like you!