# What causes "More is not recognized..." error when running Postgresql 11 on a Windows machine?

Tags: windows, postgresql, psql

I keep getting this error:

> more is not a recognized internal or external command.

when I run this command,

```
 SELECT * FROM users;
```

I am new to Postgres. I had to set my path multiple times to: `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bins`

Comment: The error is suggesting that you are trying to run a command with "more" in it.   When you run your SQL query; have you already connected to the database?  If so, can you share your connection string information?

Also, when you set your path, are you appending the Postgres bin location, or are you overwriting your existing path when setting it?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are using `psql`.

When the result of query exceeds the size of the console window, psql tries to use a pager to provide some basic scrolling facility in the result. By default this is the command `more`. Although I find it hard to believe that your system has no "more" command, you can turn off its usage.

Inside `psql` run:

```
arthur=> \pset pager off
Pager usage is off.
arthur=>
```

More details [in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html)

Related question:

- [PostgreSQL disable more output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180179)
- [customize pager in psql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474138)