# PostgreSQL: 'more' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, psql

I can log into the psql superuser and the databases through the terminal but no command works and gives me an error: 'more' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

I have gone online and tried everything. I have specified a path to system32, my C drive, psql bin, lib, and even data, but nothing seems to work. In a last ditch effort I tried reinstalling psql but the issue persists.

If you have any idea how to fix it, please help.
(I am using version 12.5 of psql on Windows.)

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XqrQ.png)

Comment: Randomly changing things isn't going to help. Find out where `more.com` file is located, and add that specific directory to your PATH. If you don't know how to search for a file on your computer, ask at [su] for help. For me, it's in the C:\Windows\System32 folder, which should already be on your PATH.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes "More is not recognized..." error when running Postgresql 11 on a Windows machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58946133/what-causes-more-is-not-recognized-error-when-running-postgresql-11-on-a-wi)