# How to show data in a table by using psql command line interface?

Tags: psql

Is there a way to show all the content inside a table by using psql command line interface?

I can use `\list` to show all the databases, `\d` to show all the tables, but how can I show all the data in a table?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9178406/postgresql-command-to-see-the-table-data this might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 290, accepted):

Newer versions: (from 8.4 - [mentioned in release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/8.4.0/#AEN137123))

```
TABLE mytablename;
```

Longer but works on all versions:

```
SELECT * FROM mytablename;
```

You may wish to use `\x` first if it's a wide table, for readability.

For long data:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 10;
```

or similar.

For wide data (big rows), in the `psql` command line client, it's useful to use `\x` to show the rows in key/value form instead of tabulated, e.g.

```
 \x
SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 10;
```

Note that in all cases the semicolon at the end is important.

Comment: A useful addition to the above answer, for when dealing with larger tables, is to add `LIMIT 100` to your command, so you can view just the first 100 (or as many as you want) rows.

Comment: Only capital letters work for the SQL command.  So "select * from ..." won't work.  You must use "SELECT * FROM ..." (well, in version 9.1 anyway)

Comment: @MacGyver That has not been true of any even vaguely recent PostgreSQL version. I used Pg as far back as 7.2 and it didn't care about capital vs lowercase (except for identifier-quoting rules around mixed-case identifier names like `"MyTable"` vs `MyTable`).

Comment: That was the reason I came to this question because I simply could not display data.  I had been using the lowercase letters.  When I tried the uppercase, I got it to work, as odd as it sounds.  Although I cannot reproduce now, I will keep my comments and come back if I find it failing again.

Comment: Although `TABLE mytablename;` works, I can't seem to find information about it in the documentation (I can't find it at all), can you provide me with a link or a way to find more info about it? @CraigRinger

Comment: @AntonKahwaji Its available from version 8.4. Please refer [Official Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/sql-select.html#SQL-TABLE)

Comment: @MacGyver my queries returned nothing because I was forgetting the semicolon at the end. Maybe you were running into this same issue?

Comment: For a long table data (> 500 rows) how do I view all of the rows in my gitbash terminal?  When I do ``SELECT * FROM`` It only displays 30 odd rows and then there is a ``--More--`` comment at the bottom.

Comment: @AmritRaj You are using a pager. See the documentation for `psql`. Typically the space or enter key advances the pager. You can disable use of the pager in `psql` per the documentation.

Comment: Is there a way to change display mode for one query only, temporarily?

Comment: @Rafs Not conveniently. You can do something like `\x \\ select 1 \g \x` but it doesn't seem to play nice with non-interactive invocations like `psql -c`

Answer (score 48):

Step 1. Check the display mode is "on" by using

```
\x
```

Step 2. Don't forget the `;`

I tried for fifteen minutes just because I forgot the semicolon.

You can choose to use uppercase for great format looking.

```
TABLE users;
```

And you will get something like

[image]

Comment: Why is UPPERCASE needed?

Comment: just look better

Comment: I agree, but it won't affect the functionality, hence my question.

Answer (score 15):

On **Windows** use the name of the table in quotes:
`TABLE "user";` or `SELECT * FROM "user";`

Comment: I don't understand what benefit the "" will give when there are no spaces or capitalisation in the table names

Answer (score 5):

you should use quotes

example =>

```
1) \c mytablename
2) SELECT * FROM "mytablename";  OR TABLE "mytablename";
```

Answer (score 4):

**postgres commande line**

1. to show databases : \l
2. to show tables : \dt
3. to show data in table x : SELECT * FROM "x";
4. to exit : \q

Answer (score 3):

If you use schemas, the following will be correct:

```
SELECT * FROM "schema-name"."table-name";
```